# Internet Explorer hangs up when window is not active while using setinterval with some SVG animation

Tags: jquery, svg, setinterval, internet-explorer-11, freeze

I am using Internet Explorer 11 with jQuery and raphaeljs. The problem I am facing is this that I am animating some lines on SVG after every 10 secs (using setInterval). If the Internet Explorer window is active it works fine but as soon as I switch to another window and then come back to Internet Explorer it's hanged and then I need to close it and reopen the webpage in the new instance of Internet Explorer.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    hideContextMenu();
    //ShowDeliveryTimeDial();
    //ShowRevenueDial();

    DisplayGraph();
    var refresh = setInterval(DisplayGraphInt, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Does that work fine with chrome/firefox?

Comment: working fine with chrome but didn't check with firefox

Comment: use setTimeOut instead of setInterval working fine for me